# How to get the parent div when using Dojo on click?

Tags: javascript, dojo, attributes, click

I'm dynamically creating a `div` object, and then appending `spans` to it based on data from a user's query.

I'm using `on(featureDiv, "click", featureClicked);`

And then I have:

```
function featureClicked(result) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that this returns the `span` object if that's what's clicked on. However, I only want to get the `div` because I place a unique ID that I need to access to use in another query depending on which `div` the user selects.

How can I always the the `div` object instead of the `span` object using `on`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discribed by @Himanshu , when attaching the click event to your div ,

to get the element in wihch the event was attached , you've to use `event.currentTarget` ,

so if you click on your spans, the `event.target` will refer to the current clicked node (the span ) , and the `event.currentTarget` will refer to the div ( in wich the event was attached ).

See below Working Sample :

```js
require(["dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/parser", "dojo/ready"], function(domConstruct, dom, On, parser, ready) {
  ready(function() {
      var elment = domConstruct.create('div', {
        'id': 'myDivId'
      }, "container");

      var span1 = domConstruct.create('span', {
        'id': 'myspan1',
        'innerHTML': 'span 1<br>'
      },);
      var span2 = domConstruct.create('span', {
        'id': 'myspan2',
        'innerHTML': 'span 2<br>'
      },);


      domConstruct.place(span1, elment , "last");
      domConstruct.place(span2, elment , "last");

      
      On(elment, "click", function (evt) {
          console.log("click target elemnt id is : ",evt.target.id);
          console.log("click parent currentTarget : ",evt.currentTarget.id);
          dom.byId("event").innerHTML = "click on : "+evt.target.id+" event attached on :"+evt.currentTarget.id;
      });
    
  });
});
```

```css
#myDivId {
  border:1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  dojoConfig = {
    isDebug: true,
    async: true,
    parseOnLoad: true
  }
</script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="container"></div>

<strong><div id="event" style="color:green"></div></strong>
```

Comment: This was helpful, thank you. But I do have a question. When I log just the `evt` object, the `currentTarget` shows as `null`, but when I log the `evt.currentTarget` it does return the `div` object. Why is it saying `null`? That's most likely why I couldn't figure it out myself.

Comment: you applied same code here ? and in wich browser you're trying this :)

Comment: Yeah, I used your code, and it did work but when I manually view the `evt.currentTarget` in the dev console, it shows as `null` - even though the code returns a value. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: this hapen when clicking the span ? could you make a fiddle ? because every things seems to work fine !

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how the click event is working over here. When an event has been attached to a parent element and the event gets triggered from the child element, the `event.target` property will return the element that has triggered the event. And the `event.currentTarget` property will return the element on which the event has been attached, i.e, the parent element.

So, to get the `div` element, you will have to access the `event.currentTarget` property.

Quoting from [this blog post](http://www.qc4blog.com/?p=650):

> - event.target is the node from which the event originated, ie. wherever you place your event listener (on `<p>` or `<span>`), event.target refers to  node (where user clicked)
> - event.currentTarget, on the opposite, refers to the node on which current-event listener was attached. Ie. if we attached our event listener on `<p>` node, then event.currentTarget refers to `<p>` while event.target still refers to `<span>`.

Comment: This was helpful, thank you. But I do have a question. When I log just the `evt` object, the `currentTarget` shows as `null`, but when I log the `evt.currentTarget` it does return the `div` object. Why is it saying `null`? That's most likely why I couldn't figure it out myself.